# How to add a script (bash script) to my linux image developed in yocto?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I am developing a script to install packages in a linux image developed using yocto. Currently, I send the .sh script by scp to my device with the linux image, but I want to install this script directly in the linux image, and when for the device to have the .sh file when it boots. How can I do this in yocto? Do I need to create a recipe for this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a recipe and a systemd services to enable it a boot time if you want to.
The architecture should be like this:

```
my_script/
├── files
│   ├── my_script.service
│   └── my_script.sh
└── my_recipe.bb
```

Your recipe should look like this,

my_recipe.bb:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

SRC_URI = "file://myscript.service"

SRC_URI += "file://myscript.sh"

  
inherit systemd

do_install() {

install -Dm0755 ${WORKDIR}/my_script.sh ${D}/usr/bin/my_script.sh
install -Dm0644 ${WORKDIR}/my_script.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/my_script.service

}


SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "my_script.service"
```

Of course, this should be in a meta-layer that is already in your conf/bblayers.conf
Otherwise create it and add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

@amolina I guess you need add your shell script to /etc/init.d for the purposes of running it on OS boot.

You can inherit update-rc.d class and define INITSCRIPT_NAME/PARAMS in
your recipe.

More details can be found in this link [yocto manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-update-rc.d)

Reference : [add custom script to yocto](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/topic/61333030?p=,,,20,0,0,0::,,,0,0,0,61333030#)